# Ubuntu 18.04 Boots with flashing underscore after install

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

Today I decided to switch from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS . I tried the Live Demo thing and everything worked good , not even a single problem . I decided to install Ubuntu over my Win10 OS (I erased everything) . I did a Normal Installation with the drivers install checked .

Installation was normal , no errors or something , then I restarted my PC . After the restart , I got a Black screen with a flashing underscore in my upper left corner . 
I tried to follow lots of tutorials , pressing buttons , reinstalling . Nothing worked so far .

I didn't understand anything from people saying to boot with GRUB . How do I do that ? What should I do now ?

I'm using an Acer Aspire with Intel Celeron  and INTEL HD Graphics , old from 2013-2014 . EDIT : It has 64 bit , 6GB of ram and 1.8 GHz Dual Core.

Comment: in the bios the Boot mode should be selected as UEFI

Comment: and try this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: Thank you ! This really helped me out . I'm now able to boot normally , with no complications.